# I want to display a text as it is in the properties file with thymeleaf template engine

Tags: html, thymeleaf, properties-file

I have 2 files
message_ar.properties and messages_fr.properties for the internationalization

In my html file I want to display the correct label for a confirm message

I'm using the thymeleaf as a template engine

```
    <a th:onclick="return confirm('#{label.deleteEmployee}')"
```

The browser displays the confirm message as it is in the html file!!

[image]

I want to display the confirm message as it is in the properties file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it differently :

```
<a th:if="#{direction}== 'rtl'" th:onclick="return confirm('هل نريد الحذف فعلا؟')" ...
<a th:unless="#{direction}== 'rtl'" th:onclick="return confirm('Voulez vous vraiment supprimer cet employé?')"...
```